# Adding Python 3.x Installation Location to PATH error

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip, centos

I have Python 2 available at

```
# which python
/bin/python

# python --version
Python 2.7.5
```

And I am installing python 3.7 using following article https://wiki.centos-webpanel.com/install-django

After installing python

```
# cd /usr/local/src
# wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3.tgz
# tar xvf Python-3.7.3.tgz
# cd Python-3.7.3
# ./configure --with-ensurepip=install --enable-shared
# make
# make install
# ln -s /usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0 /usr/lib64/libpython3.7m.so.1.0
```

When i am upgrading pip using following command it gives command not found

```
# pip3.7 install --upgrade pip
bash: pip3.7: command not found
```

I tried

```
# python3.7 pip install --upgrade pip
bash: python3.7: command not found
```

Note: Please note that after installation, the new python binary path will be located at /usr/local/bin/python

**Edit1:** I have created symslink using following command

```
[root@host Python-3.7.3]# ln -s /usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0 /usr/lib64/libpython3.7m.so.1.0
[root@host Python-3.7.3]# cd /usr/local/lib/
[root@host lib]# ll
total 13380
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       20 Jul  7 11:09 libpython3.7m.so -> libpython3.7m.so.1.0
-r-xr-xr-x.  1 root root 13678000 Jul  7 11:09 libpython3.7m.so.1.0
-r-xr-xr-x.  1 root root     7680 Jul  7 11:09 libpython3.so
drwxr-xr-x. 15 root root      288 Jun 23 07:11 php
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root       67 Jul  7 11:09 pkgconfig
drwxr-xr-x. 35 root root     8192 Jul  7 11:09 python3.7
```

**EDIT2:**

```
[root@host python3.7]# which python3
/usr/bin/which: no python3 in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
```

**EDIT3:**

```
[root@host usr]# cd /usr/local/bin
[root@host bin]# ll
total 23580
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root        8 Jul  7 11:09 2to3 -> 2to3-3.7
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root      101 Jul  7 11:09 2to3-3.7
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root      241 Jul  2 19:24 easy_install-3.7
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root        7 Jul  7 11:09 idle3 -> idle3.7
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root       99 Jul  7 11:09 idle3.7
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root      817 Jul 20  2018 pear
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root      838 Jul 20  2018 peardev
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root      754 Jul 20  2018 pecl
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root        9 Jun 23 07:11 phar -> phar.phar
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    14829 Jul 20  2018 phar.phar
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 12036016 Jul 20  2018 php
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 12009264 Jul 20  2018 php-cgi
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     3232 Jul 20  2018 php-config
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     4526 Jul 20  2018 phpize
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root      223 Jul  2 19:24 pip3
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root      223 Jul  2 19:24 pip3.7
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root        8 Jul  7 11:09 pydoc3 -> pydoc3.7
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root       84 Jul  7 11:09 pydoc3.7
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root        9 Jul  7 11:09 python3 -> python3.7
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    11200 Jul  7 11:09 python3.7
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       17 Jul  7 11:09 python3.7-config -> python3.7m-config
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    11200 Jul  7 11:09 python3.7m
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     3097 Jul  7 11:09 python3.7m-config
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       16 Jul  7 11:09 python3-config -> python3.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       10 Jul  7 11:09 pyvenv -> pyvenv-3.7
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root      441 Jul  7 11:09 pyvenv-3.7
```

Comment: Do you have in `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin` an executable or symbolic link named "python3.7" is no, that is why python3.7 is not recognized

Comment: Also, I do not know CentOS, but usually when you compile and install your own things in UNIX they go inside the `/opt` folder. I recomend you (if possible) to repeat all the process but inside the `/opt` folder and do `sudo make install`

Comment: @DanielRodríguez, Please check my Edit I have added symbolic link reference.

Comment: I don't think */usr/local/lib/* is in the *PATH*. As a workaround, use the full name: */usr/local/lib/python3.7* (although I don't know why is the executable located there).

Comment: @MaqsudInamdar ok, then I think is because your python3.7 file is in the wrong directory. To launch a command from the terminal you need to have it in the `/usr/local/bin` folder, not in the `/usr/local/lib` as you have it

Comment: @DanielRodríguez I do have python3.7 in `/usr/local/bin`. Please check my EDIT5.

Comment: @MaqsudInamdar your edit 2 says `(/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)` I think those are the paths where it is looking for commands. You can either place the python3.7 command inside `/usr/bin` or include `/usr/local/bin` into your PATH. If none of that works... I'm sorry but I do not have more ideas

Answer (score -1):

I think you should go to python3.7 from your terminal and use this:
python3.x -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: It's still giving me `bash: python3.7: command not found` error. Please check my EDIT2

Comment: try it with python3 not python3.7

Comment: when you type in terminal: which python3  what path do you get?

Comment: Running python3 gives me `Could not import runpy module`

Comment: what about when you run which python3 ?

Comment: Please check my ***EDIT3:***

Comment: ok i ask you to run this command "which python3" and give me the result please

Comment: I have runned `which python3` please check.

Comment: Now i can't figure the problem but try to reinstall python using "sudo apt install python3"

cause i think "which python3" should return "/usr/bin/python" not like this

Comment: Maybe it has to do something with PATH